# How to hide an object with shape keys

Tags: animation, shape-keys

My problem is that the character doesn't have her eyelashes visible while her eyes are opened, and the shape key I made only shows the eyelashes once the eyes are completely closed, but I want the eyelashes go along while the eyes are closing, instead of appearing from inside the head once the eyes are closed.

[image: Opened Eyes]
[image: Closing Eyes (no eyelashes)]
[image: Closed Eyes (Eyelashes)]

[A video showing how my shape key works at the moment](https://youtu.be/8K8aGUiWlps)

Is there a way to hide the eyelashes in front of the eyes and make them appear once the eyes are starting to close?
Or a way to make the eyelashes appear in front of the eyes once the shape key starts to work.

Comment: why don't you give your eyelashes a shape key as well and drive both shapekeys with e.g. one custom property + driver? or just one shapekey and a "copy" driver to the other shapekey value?

Comment: @Chris How do the driver and custom property work? I received the same advice in Discord server, but the guy didn't explain them and from the tutorials I found on youtube, none of them explained the function very well :/

Comment: Hi Kay, honestly, there are a lot of even great tutorials on yt about drivers, custom properties and shapekeys. And it is not the sense of this forum to give you tutorial answers. This site is for very specific questions where you are stuck at, e.g. how can i drive my eyelashes with a driver?  But "normally" the "normal" things you should learn about tutorials. Both functions are very (!) basic and quite easy to understand with a good tutorial. just one example for drivers: https://youtu.be/M4GPVs2xKE8